# Links don't work if we concatenate css/js files from multiple folders

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, gruntjs, concatenation

I am using grunt with usemin. I have got many different folders for css, ie many css files are scattered over the project across many folders and subfolders, with relative urls for images, backgrounds, fonts,etc.

When I tried concatenating using usemin, all css files were combined, but many css urls/links were not working bcz they were not updated according to new location. All links to resources that they were pointing to were broken because the new css code moved to a new common css location alongside the html files. They should have pointed to correct resources by updating links automatically according to previous and new positions.
Same problem for js also.

Is there a solution for this? Please help!

Comment: I don't think there is any way that the links would also get updated when you use usemin. The best thing I would suggest is to first place all the css together, all js together, update the links manually and then use usemin.

I too would like to know if there is any way to auto update links when using usemin.

Comment: @Rishabh ya i searched a lot but did not got the answer yet. actually sometimes for better file organisation we can put all similar files together. that's why i need some solution.